# LaTeX changebars with pdflscape

Tags: latexdiff, pdflscape, changebar

I have a very long document with a large number of tables in the appendices. These tables were a tad wide, so I change the page layout to landscape using the `landscape` command. To make it readable by humans, I include the `pdflscape` package which kindly rotates the pages when viewed on a computer screen.

Now, I'm trying to do change-bars using `latexdiff` and it seems to not care much for landscape pages. The bar doesn't actually seem to line up with anything (in fact, it seems to not even be visible if there are lengthy footers). I'm wondering if there is a clever solution to this problem - perhaps adjusting margins?

I tried looking through the documentation for `pdflscape` and nothing is sticking out to me for this one.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,portrait,left=1in,right=1.5in,top=1.5in,bottom=1in,headheight=1in,headsep=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,traceon,rightbars]{changebar}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\cbstart{I have correct changebar.}\cbend
\begin{landscape}
\cbstart{I do not have correct changebars}\cbend
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\cbstart` does not take a required argument - only an optional one. `outerbars` and `rightbars` are inconsistent. (This doesn't solve the problem - it just improves the coherence.)

Comment: Right, `\cbstart` doesn't take any arguments - the braces were just to be consistent with how `\DIFadd` works with `latexdiff`. Good catch on `outerbars` - I misread that section of the manual.

Comment: I wouldn't mind overriding the `\changebarsep` to some hard-coded value that pushes the bars to the correct place, but it seems that this can only be set once in the preamble? Not sure why, because `\changebarwidth` can be changed anywhere... Any idea why?

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution than the one proposed by touhami below?

Comment: @FRob I'm no longer on that project, but we were satisfied with the provided solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.

**Edit** here is with the original settings

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,traceon,rightbars]{changebar}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document} 
\cbstart{I have correct changebars}\cbend

\begin{landscape}
\addtolength{\changebarsep}{\hsize}
\makeatletter\cb@positions\makeatother

\cbstart{I have correct changebars}\cbend 
\blindtext

\end{landscape}
\makeatletter\cb@positions\makeatother

\cbstart{I have correct changebars}\cbend 
\blindtext 
\end{document}
```

and this with `typearea` package

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[pdftex,traceon,rightbars]{changebar}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{landscape}{%
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=last}
\cb@positions}{%
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=last}
\cb@positions}
\makeatother 

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document} 
\cbstart{I have correct changebars}\cbend
\blindtext 

\begin{landscape}
\cbstart{I have correct changebars}\cbend 
\blindtext
\end{landscape}

\cbstart{I have correct changebars}\cbend 
\blindtext 
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile that, the landscape page isn't really landscape... it looks like the text box is landscape but the paper remains portrait.

Comment: you don't want it like this? I think it's better. I will see.

Comment: I mean, the text and bars are off the edge and can't be seen when viewing the PDF. But ideally the landscape functionality from original example since the final document will be printed, and it has headers/footers.

Comment: @JacobSchaer answer edited

Comment: I'm going to test more on Monday and mark this as the answer if I don't find anything. So far it looks to be working with everything I have. I did notice that loading the `pdflscape` package *before* the `changebar` package will cause the landscape pages to not work correctly, so that was part of my problem during earlier testing.

Comment: @touhami How to make the first changebar and the second changebar with `different changebarsep` in a portrait page?